# How to load system properties and custom resources in the Spring 4.1.0 application context?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have the following configuration.

```
<bean id="appSystemProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/database_connection.properties
                </value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true" />
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="${app.environment}SessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

while reading the "app.environment" system property, getting the following exception.

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/hibernate-config.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean '${app.environment}SessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '${app.environment}SessionFactory' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1471)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
```

Framework versions:

```
Spring: 4.1.0.RELEASE
Hibernate: 4.3.6.Final
```

System property:

```
-Dapp.environment=dev
```

Note: when I remove the locations property from "appSystemProperties" bean, I am able to see the value of "app.environment" value.  Since I need both System properties & custom resource properties, I have added locations property.

How to make it work both? Any help?

Comment: i noticed that you have ref="${app.environment}SessionFactory", is this meant to be the case or are you meant to be using ref="${app.environment}"?

Comment: ref="${app.environment}SessionFactory" is correct. I want to refer this as "devSessionFactory" during runtime.

Comment: Looking around a bit I believe the problem is you have conflicts with properties. Is your app.environment being set as System variable as well as a value within database_connections.properties?

Comment: I am confident and there is no conflict.

Answer (score 0):

My configuration is good. I found the issue. I was passing the environment value  "-Dapp.environment=dev" in the eclipse debug configuration ->  VM arguments.

Now i removed from the above place and passing the value from Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Select the active JRE -> Default VM arguments.

[image]

Now all working fine. Thank you @Aeseir for  your pointers and time.